# Inequality regarding weak-* convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $X$ be a normed linear space, $\psi \in X^{*}$ and $\displaystyle \{\psi_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ a sequence in $X^{*}$. Show that if $\displaystyle \{\psi_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N}$ converges weak-${*}$ to $\psi$ then:

$$\|\psi\| \le \lim \sup \|\psi_n\|$$

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated. I am not well acquainted with weak-$*$ convergence. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weak-$*$-convergence gives you

$$\|\psi(x)\| \le \lim \sup \|\psi_n(x)\|$$

for every $x\in X$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: I don't think so...

Comment: @Stefan Strange. You've already accepted an answer, and asked me to take a look at it...

Answer (score 4):

By definition of $weak^*$ convergence,
$$ \forall x\in X,\quad \psi_n(x)\to \psi(x)
$$
Usually we assume $\psi\in X^*:\ X \to \mathbb{C}$
$$ \psi_n(x)\to \psi(x)\quad \Rightarrow \quad |\psi(x)|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\psi_n(x)|
$$
Since $|\psi_n(x)|\le \|\psi_n\|\cdot \|x\|,$
$$\ \lim_{n\to \infty}|\psi_n(x)|=\limsup_{n\to \infty}|\psi_n(x)|\le \limsup_{n\to \infty}|\|\psi_n\|\cdot \|x\||=\|x\|\cdot \limsup_{n\to \infty}\|\psi_n\|
$$
$$ \Rightarrow \quad|\psi(x)|=\lim_{n\to \infty}|\psi_n(x)|\le \|x\|\cdot\limsup_{n\to \infty}\|\psi_n\|
$$

By definition, we obtain
$$ \|\psi\|\le \limsup_{n\to \infty}\|\psi_n\|
$$

Comment: I am immensely grateful! Thank you for your time and for taking the trouble to help me!