# Distance of point for a set in linear spaces

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $X$ a normed linear spaces, $Y \subset X$ a subspace and $z \in X$ an arbitrary point. How can we show that:

$$\text{dist} (z, Y) = \sup \{\psi(z) \ | \ \|\psi\| = 1, \psi \equiv 0 \ \text{on} \ Y\}$$

Here is a definition of the [distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance#Distances_between_sets_and_between_a_point_and_a_set).

Comment: People can probably _guess_ what $\phi$ is supposed to be, but you should probably say it explicitly just to be sure.

Comment: I was confused when I saw it. The problem does not specify it either. Could you post what it is?

Comment: I can _guess_ that it's a linear function of some sort? But what does it mean to take its norm?

Comment: I thought the same. Some linear function from $X$ to itself I would guess.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need extra conditions:

1. $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$
2. $\psi\in X^*$

Now let's prove it:

- The following theorem is one of the principal applications of the *Hahn-Banach* theorem to normed vector space.

If $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$ and $z\in X$, there exists $\psi\in X^*$ such that $\psi(z)\not=0$ and $\psi|_Y=0$. $\psi$ can be taken to satisfy $\|\psi\|=1$ and $\psi(z)=$ Dist$(z,Y)$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{Dist}(z,Y)\le \sup\,\{\psi (z)\ |\  \|\psi\|=1,\ \psi|_Y=0\}$

- If $\|\psi\|=1$ and $\psi|_Y=0$, for any $y\in Y$
  $$ |\psi(z)|=|\psi(z)-\psi(y)|\le\|\psi\|\cdot \|z-y\|=\|z-y\| \  \Rightarrow \  \psi(z)\le \operatorname{Dist}(z,Y)
  $$
  $$ \Rightarrow \quad \sup\,\{\psi (z)\ |\  \|\psi\|=1,\ \psi|_Y=0\}\le \operatorname{Dist}(z,Y).
  $$

Based on the above two points, this problem can be solved.

Comment: Do you think you could take a look at this one too? It's also mine. I don't know how to continue from where the first answer left me. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318002/inequality-regarding-weak-convergence